# After update, Windows 10 stop outgoing network connections while still connected to internet?

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-10-v1809

My issue is that every 2-6 hours, my internet connection seems to 'drop.' Specifically:

After X hours of being connected to the internet, my Windows 10 (Version 1809) desktop using a usb wifi dongle (Asus USB-AC56) will remain `Connected, Secure` to my network. However, it will stop any new connections.

eg: If I am in a video game (multiplayer match) it will continue without issue, but after the game it will disconnect me. Attempts to reconnect will fail. -- During the match, any attempt to access a website via browser will fail. Going into the Windows network settings and toggling `on -> off -> on` will fix. Similarly, unplugging the adapter and re-plugging will also fix.

Both during and after the above example, the taskbar wifi claims it is connected to the local wifi network.

I have attempted typical fixes, each has not fixed this issue:

- Ran Troubleshooter
- Re-installed driver
- Turned off USB and Network Adapter Power Management in Device Manager
- Ran chkdsk, reset firewall
- Used a different router
- Google'd for similar issues (no results)

I *think* I remember this issue happening the last time I updated to a major version, but I cannot remember how I fixed it.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the recent update to see if that fixes it?

Comment: What would that accomplish though? The idea is to be on the latest update without this issue

Comment: It would accomplish fixing your issue.

Comment: But it wouldn't... because then I wouldn't be on the latest update. The solution of "reinstall your OS" is hardly ever acceptable